# What does this schematic symbol of a dashed cylinder, connected to ground, around a wire represent?

Tags: schematics

What is this symbol from an automotive schematic?

[image: wire with cylinder around it, connected to ground]

Answer (score 9):

That represents the shielding on the cable.

Comment: Oh ok I see, thanks. That just confuses me more though, I'm not sure why there needs to be shielding on that wire. I guess it's not the simple high/low signal I'd hoped for. :o(

Comment: @Jon: The shielding doesn't have anything to do with the signal. The symbol tells you that the ground reference is carried on the outside of the cable, as in a coaxial cable. With blk and the center cable, you can find the signal you're looking for.

Comment: Not to disappoint, but it would be unusual that a simple high/low signal would be shielded in an automotive application.  It's likely that your signal is either a sensor or one wire communication bus.

Comment: @HikeOnPast It is a signal from a seat weight sensor (strain gauge) to the ECU, however...there is a module in between which is a black box to me. I'm just trying to guess at what the signal might be, so being shielded I'd guess either a very small voltage, or PWM? Here's the rest of the context (added to original question)

Comment: @Jon, please make a new question (and if possible, restore your prior one here).  The goal of the community is to provide useful information to others as well.